# Pushing repo from command line to remote

Tags: git

What are the differences between the following three commands when trying to push a local repo to remote. Note that my remote repo is **empty**

```
git push -u origin master
git push -u origin main 
git push -u origin --all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the differences between the following three commands ...

> 1. `git push -u origin master`

This has your Git look up the URL stored under the name `origin` and call up some Git to talk with it using that URL.  (This part will repeat for subsequent commands.)  Then:

- your Git uses your `master` branch to locate the commit(s) to send;
- your Git offers the latest such commit to their Git;
- their Git decides if it needs that commit, or already has it; if they do need that commit, your Git offers its parent(s) as well; this continues until you either find a commit they already have (that you both share) or you've run out of commits to offer because you have reached the start of the repository;
- your Git sends the commits that you have, that they don't;
- and last, your Git asks their Git to create or update their branch name `master`.  Their branch name should identify the same commit that your branch name identifies.  If they agree to this, your Git sets your branch name's *upstream* to `origin/master`.

The above assumes that `master` actually exists in your repository as a branch name (that `refs/heads/master` is a valid, existing ref-name).

> 2. `git push -u origin main`

This is almost exactly the same as before, with two changes:

- your Git uses your branch name `main` to locate the final commit to send; and
- at the end, your Git asks their Git to set *their* branch name `main`.  If this succeeds, your Git sets your `main`'s upstream setting to `origin/main`.

> 3. `git push -u origin --all`

Here, your Git calls up their Git as before.  But instead of looking up your `main` or your `master`, your Git looks for *all* of your branch names.  That is, your Git runs the equivalent of:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads
```

(try it) or `git branch` (try it).  For *each* such branch name, your Git finds the commit identified by that branch name.

This list of commit hash IDs, as found by all your branch names, becomes the set of commits that your Git will offer to their Git.  For each commit hash ID that they say they would like, your Git must find those commits' parent hash IDs and offer those.  In this way, your Git will end up offering, to their Git, every commit that you have reachable in your repository by all of your branch names, excluding any commits that they say they already have, and any commits that precede those commits (which by implication they also have).

Your Git will then package up this entire series of commits and send them.  Then, for each branch name, your Git will ask that their Git create or update a branch of the same name in *their* repository.  For each one that succeeds, your Git will set your (local) branch's upstream to your remote-tracking name for that same branch: for instance, if you have branches `a-branch`, `b-branch`, `main`, and `z-branch`, and they accept `a-branch` and `z-branch` but reject both `b-branch` and `main`, your Git will now set the upstream for `a-branch` to `origin/a-branch`, and the upstream for `z-branch` to `origin/z-branch`.

In each case, the overall `git push` command succeeds (and therefore exits with a success status, i.e., zero) if it successfully sent any required commits *and* got the other Git to create or update a branch of the corresponding name.

> Note that my remote repo is **empty**

That means all the pushes are likely to succeed, provided you have the right branch names in the local repository.  But it's possible for the remote repo to reject commits and/or branch names for any reason, based on any scripts written specifically for that repository.  If you're using a web hosting site like GitHub for the remote, those web sites provide pre-written scripts that can reject certain items for pre-written reasons (the details will depend on the hosting site).

Comment: absolutely fantastic answer. Currently my branch name in local is master. I need to have the main branch named in the repo to "main".  I cant just push origin main right ? since the branch in loca is called master.

Comment: Branch names are specific to each repository, though—as the above shows—Git gives you a nice short-cut when you use the *same* name on each "side" of a push operation. So you *could* run `git push origin master:main`, which uses your `master` to find commit hash IDs, but in the end, asks their Git to set *their* `main`. But it's easier to just rename your existing `master` to `main`: `git branch -m main` while on `master`.

Comment: Is there a way to have it constantly named main . it seems that everytime i initizalize git repo in a local folder, it is by default named master

Comment: `git init` grew new options in recent versions of Git. In 2.28.0, `git init` grew `-b <branch>` aka `--initial-branch-name <branch>`. In 2.30, `git init` began using a new configuration field, `init.defaultBranch`. If your Git predates either of these, you'd need to upgrade to use either method. You can make an alias that you use instead of `git init` that runs `git init` and then `git checkout -b main`, if that's easier than upgrading.

Answer (score 3):

`git push -u origin master` will push to the `master` branch.

`git push -u origin main` will push to the `main` branch.

`git push -u origin --all` will push all local branches.

The `-u` option will with all three add a tracking reference for each successfully pushed or up to date branch.

All this information can easily be taken from *git-push*(1)